# Flash Pro - AS3 embeded font not Showing up on Button Label in iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, fonts, embedded-fonts

So I have an annoying issue that I can't solve. I am creating an app in Flash Pro/AS3 for iOS. I have a button whose label font I want to change:

```
var ButtonTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Showcard Gothic", 120);
//ButtonTextFormat.size         = 120;
//ButtonTextFormat.font         = "Showcard Gothic";
//ButtonTextFormat.embedFonts           = true;
ButtonTextFormat.color          = 0x00FF00;
//ButtonTextFormat.embedFonts = true;
SMButton.label                  = "PUSHME!";
SMButton.setStyle("textFormat", ButtonTextFormat);
```

I just used the standard button found in the Components Toolbox in Flash.
It displays correctly during debug, but once loaded into the iPhone, the label is changed to a default font.

I did embed the desired font through `Text>Font Embedding...` and it works for a text field that I have, but why not the button label?

I've tried `ButtonTextFormat.embedFonts = true;` but I get an error:

```
1119: Access of possibly undefined property embedFonts through a reference with static type flash.text:TextFormat.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Those components are not meant to be used on mobile devices.

Comment: Yet they work. at least for quick prototyping purposes. I'd like to solve the problem now incase I run into it later though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*embedFonts* property is for TextField class, not for TextFormat class.

Follow this instructions to embed and use your embeded font properly [Embedding Fonts for Components in Flash](http://www.graphicmania.net/embedding-fonts-for-components-in-flash/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. For components, you must set embedFonts with the .setStyle() method.

```
SMButton.setStyle("fontFamily", "Showcard Gothic");
SMButton.setStyle("embedFonts", true);
```

In the Flash IDE, you may need to add your font to the Library, and then export for ActionScript.    The class name "TreasureMapDeadhand" for example.

Then in your document class:

```
import flash.text.Font;

Font.registerFont(TreasureMapDeadhand);
```

Another option if your linking your font multiple times, although not necessary, is store your font in a public var.

```
public var f:Font = new TreasureMapDeadhand();

SMButton.setStyle("fontFamily", f.fontName);
SMButton.setStyle("embedFonts", true);
```

Anyway, I hope this helps!